# Facebook sample puzzle: Towers of Hanoi

Tags: facebook, algorithm, recursion, towers-of-hanoi

Here is a question from Facebook hiring sample test.

There are K pegs. Each peg can hold discs in decreasing order of radius when looked from bottom to top of the peg. There are N discs which have radius 1 to N; Given the initial configuration of the pegs and the final configuration of the pegs, output the moves required to transform from the initial to final configuration. You are required to do the transformations in minimal number of moves.

A move consists of picking the topmost disc of any one of the pegs and placing it on top of any other peg.
At any point of time, the decreasing radius property of all the pegs must be maintained.

> Constraints:

1<= N<=8

3<= K<=5

> Input Format:

N K

2nd line contains N integers. Each integer is in the range 1 to K where the i-th integer denotes the peg to which disc of radius i is present in the initial configuration.

3rd line denotes the final configuration in a format similar to the initial configuration.

> Output Format:

The first line contains M - The minimal number of moves required to complete the transformation.

The following M lines describe a move, by a peg number to pick from and a peg number to place on.
If there are more than one solutions, it's sufficient to output any one of them. You can assume, there is always a solution with less than 7 moves and the initial confirguration will not be same as the final one.

> Sample Input #00:

2 3

1 1

2 2

> Sample Output #00:

3

1 3

1 2

3 2

> Sample Input #01:

6 4

4 2 4 3 1 1

1 1 1 1 1 1

> Sample Output #01:

5

3 1

4 3

4 1

2 1

3 1

There is no harm in discussing solution for this problem as it is a sample problem.

The solution to the classic Towers of Hanoi problem is really simple to code:

```
void hanoi(char s, char i, char d, int n)
{
     if(n>0)
     {
            hanoi(s, d, i, n-1);
            cout<<s<<":"<<d<<endl;
            hanoi(i, s, d, n-1);
     }        
}
```

The above can also be extended to a general 'k' pegs tower of hanoi. But, this knowledge is turning out to be not at all useful to design a solution to this sample puzzle. Any suggestions as to how to approach this and similar kind of problems in future?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's my dynamic programming solution that finds the optimal sequence of moves in at most O(K^N) steps, it runs in under a second for K = 5, N = 8. I hard coded the input data due to lazyness.

It is a BFS through the state space that never visits the same state twice. Then it gets the actual path by backtracking from the end to start (this part is linear with length of the optimal sequence). Basically, it is the "shortest path through a maze" algorithm, but the "maze" is the state space of the problem, the starting "location" is the initial state, and the ending "location" is the desired state.

Many similar problems can be solved this way, as long as you can define a finite state space, a "distance" between two states that your goal is to minimize, and a way to calculate which states you can move to from the current state.

For example, the "missionaries and cannibals" problem with an arbitrary number of each can be solved with this same algorithm.

Also, if you need "all optimal solutions" instead of "any optimal solution", it is easy to modify the algorithm to provide them.

```
class Program
{
    static int N = 8;
    static int K = 5;
    static List<int> StartState = new List<int> { 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 1, 5, 2 };
    static List<int> EndState = new List<int> { 1, 4, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3 };

    static LinkedList<int> StateQueue = new LinkedList<int>();
    static int[] MovesToState = new int[(int)Math.Pow(K, N)];


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < StartState.Count; i++)
        {
            StartState[i]--;
            EndState[i]--;
        }

        int startStateIndex = StateToNum(StartState);
        int endStateIndex = StateToNum(EndState);

        for (int i = 0; i < MovesToState.Length; i++)
            MovesToState[i] = -1;

        MovesToState[startStateIndex] = 0;

        StateQueue.AddFirst(startStateIndex);
        while (StateQueue.Count > 0 && MovesToState[endStateIndex] == -1)
        {
            var legalMoves = LegalMoves(StateQueue.Last.Value);
            foreach (var newStateIndex in legalMoves)
            {
                int currMoves = MovesToState[StateQueue.Last.Value];
                if (MovesToState[newStateIndex] == -1)
                {
                    MovesToState[newStateIndex] = currMoves + 1;
                    StateQueue.AddFirst(newStateIndex);
                }
            }
            StateQueue.RemoveLast();
        }

        var currStateIndex = endStateIndex;
        var moves = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
        while (currStateIndex != startStateIndex)
        {
            var legalMoves = LegalMoves(currStateIndex);
            int currMoves = MovesToState[currStateIndex];
            foreach (var prevStateIndex in legalMoves)
            {
                if (MovesToState[prevStateIndex] == MovesToState[currStateIndex] - 1)
                {
                    var currState = NumToState(currStateIndex);
                    var prevState = NumToState(prevStateIndex);
                    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
                    {
                        if (currState[i] != prevState[i])
                        {
                            moves.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(prevState[i] + 1, currState[i] + 1));
                            currStateIndex = prevStateIndex;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(MovesToState[endStateIndex]);
        moves.Reverse();
        foreach (var move in moves)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", move.Item1, move.Item2);
        }

        Console.Read();
    }

    static List<int> LegalMoves(int stateIndex)
    {
        var legalMoves = new List<int>();

        var state = NumToState(stateIndex);

        int[] minOnPeg = new int[K];
        for (int i = 0; i < minOnPeg.Length; i++)
            minOnPeg[i] = N;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < K; j++)
                if (state[i] == j && i < minOnPeg[j])
                    minOnPeg[j] = i;

        bool[] isTop = new bool[N];
        for (int i = 0; i < isTop.Length; i++)
            isTop[i] = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < K; i++)
            if (minOnPeg[i] < N)
                isTop[minOnPeg[i]] = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            if (!isTop[i])
                continue;

            for (int j = 0; j < K; j++)
            {
                if (minOnPeg[j] <= i)
                    continue;

                var tmp = state[i];
                state[i] = j;
                var newStateIndex = StateToNum(state);
                legalMoves.Add(newStateIndex);
                state[i] = tmp;
            }
        }
        return legalMoves;
    }

    static int StateToNum(List<int> state)
    {
        int r = 0;
        int f = 1;
        foreach (var peg in state)
        {
            r += f * peg;
            f *= K;
        }
        return r;
    }

    static List<int> NumToState(int num)
    {
        var r = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            r.Add(num % K);
            num = num / K;
        }
        return r;
    }
}
```

Comment: You say Dynamic Programming (DP) and BFS. These two don't usually go together, and from (very briefly) looking at your code, I don't see any DP code. Are you **sure** you know what DP is and that you used that?

Comment: Here is what the algorithm does: it first finds every point reachable in 1 move. Then it uses those points to find every point optimally reachable in 2 moves. Then it uses the points from the first 2 steps to find every point optimally reachable in 3 moves, etc. The FIFO queue is actually an optimization, the algorithm would work without StateQueue and with just MovesToState array, but it would be slower.

Answer (score 2):

an excellent resource for solving the towers of hanoi problem using recursion  http://sleepingthreads.blogspot.in/2013/05/the-power-of-recursion_3.html

Answer (score 1):

Found this [solution](http://blog.thiagogenez.com/2012/03/tower-of-hanoi-facebook-hiring-sample.html) in java. 
Basically it maps all the possible moves into a tree and performs a BFS.

Comment: The comment by Lorin in that blog was really helpful. So, +1 for finding the blog!

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice benchmark for your algorithm in the blog from the link above (please note that MAX_MOVES should be increased to 11):

```
6 4
3 3 2 1 4 1
1 4 2 2 3 4
```

Ruby version by Leandro Facchinetti [from this comment](http://blog.thiagogenez.com/2012/03/tower-of-hanoi-facebook-hiring-sample.html?showComment=1346898764182#c2085742021569767911) solves it in ~10seconds. [Java version](http://blog.thiagogenez.com/2012/03/tower-of-hanoi-facebook-hiring-sample.html?showComment=1366501251188#c2794253675341050275) by e-digga ~0.5 seconds. My python version runs in ~30ms. I'm not sure why my implementation is so fast. Here it is:

```
import sys

MAX_MOVES = 11

def valid_moves(state, K):
    pegs, tops = [-1] * K, []
    for r, peg in enumerate(state):
        if pegs[peg] < 0:
            pegs[peg] = r
            for top_r, top_peg in tops:
                yield (top_r, top_peg, peg)
            tops.append((r, peg))
    for dst_peg, peg_r in enumerate(pegs):
        if peg_r < 0:
            for top_r, top_peg in tops:
                yield (top_r, top_peg, dst_peg)

def move_apply(state, move):
    r, src, dst = move
    return state[:r] + (dst,) + state[r + 1:]

def solve_bfs(initial_state, final_state, K):
    known_states = set()
    next_states = [(initial_state, [])]
    depth = 0
    while next_states and depth < MAX_MOVES:
        states, next_states = next_states, []
        for state, moves in states:
            for move in valid_moves(state, K):
                new_state = move_apply(state, move)
                if new_state in known_states:
                    continue
                new_moves = moves + [move]
                if new_state == final_state:
                    return new_moves
                next_states.append((new_state, new_moves))
                known_states.add(new_state)
        depth += 1

lines = sys.stdin.readlines()
N, K = [int(i) for i in lines[0].strip().split()]
initial_state = tuple(int(i) - 1 for i in lines[1].strip().split())
final_state = tuple(int(i) - 1 for i in lines[2].strip().split())

solution = solve_bfs(initial_state, final_state, K)
if solution:
    print len(solution)
    for disk, src, dst in solution:
        print src + 1, dst + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

First post on here. I've used stackoverflow as a lurker but never contributed so I figured I'd do it this time since I have some code to share.

I tried this problem, too, and it took me a while to figure out! I figured I'd post my hard work here. There was no way I could have solved this problem in 45 minutes. I'm a computer engineering student (not computer science) so I am rusty on my data structures. I've never had to code a BFS before!

Anyway, my program works using the same BFS method as discussed in the previous answers but the data structures might be handled a little differently. It basically generates valid moves breadth first (implemented with a FIFO queue) and then puts the new peg/disk configurations (states) in a dictionary with the format {state: previous_state}. Once the final state has been found or the max recursion depth has been reached, the programs stops searching for new states. It then retrieves final state from the dict and backtracks through the dict to find the moves made in succession. The main data structure I use in the program is the dict with the in different states in it. I do not actually record the (from, to) peg numbers required in the output. This output is calculated when I backtrack through the dict tree by finding the one changed element between two successive states. The states are recorded as tuples in the same format as the input.

Hope this helps someone and I welcome any comments or suggestions on how I can improve my code or coding style.

```
import sys

MAX_MOVES = 10

def main():
    lines = sys.stdin.readlines()

    [discs, npegs] = map(int, lines[0].split())
    #read in the initial and final states
    istate = tuple(int(n) - 1 for n in lines[1].split())
    fstate = tuple(int(n) - 1 for n in lines[2].split())

    #call recursive function to find possible moves and 
    #generate new states to add to tree
    tree = findStates(istate, fstate, npegs)
    solution = findSolution(istate, fstate, tree)

    if solution:
        print solution[0]
        for a, b in solution[1:]:
            print "{} {}".format(a,b) 
    else:
        print "No solution found for {} max moves".format(MAX_MOVES)

def findTopDisks(state, npegs):
    """
    list the pegs with disks and the top disk radius in a dict with key being peg number
    and value being disk radius
    This function is used to find valid disks and their peg positions to make a move from
    """
    topdict = dict()
    for peg in range(npegs):
            if peg in state:
                topdict[peg] = state.index(peg)
    return topdict

def findValidMoves(state, npegs):
    """
    Finds the valid moves given the current state and number of pegs.
    Yields tuples consisting of source and destination pegs
    """
    #find the top disk of every peg number
    top_disks = findTopDisks(state, npegs)
    for from_peg, disk_r in top_disks.items():
        for dest_peg in range(npegs):
            if not top_disks.has_key(dest_peg): #dest peg is empty
                    yield (from_peg, dest_peg)
            elif top_disks[dest_peg] > disk_r:
                    yield (from_peg, dest_peg)

def findStates(istate, fstate, npegs):
    """
    Generates new states first by calling findValidMoves on current state to get valid moves.
    Then generates the new states and put them in the tree implemented using a dict.
    Key of the dict is the current state, and value is the state that leads to that state.
    """
    queue = [(istate, 0)]
    tree = {istate: None}
    while queue and (queue[0][1] < MAX_MOVES):
        cstate = queue[0][0]
        cmove = queue[0][1]
        queue.pop(0)
        #enumerate and find all valid moves and add to queue
        for from_peg, dest_peg in findValidMoves(cstate, npegs):
            if from_peg in cstate:
                nstate = list(cstate)
                nstate[cstate.index(from_peg)] = dest_peg
                nstate = tuple(nstate)
                if nstate not in tree: #new state never been found!
                    tree[nstate] = cstate
                    if nstate == fstate:
                        return tree
                    queue.append((nstate, cmove+1))
    return tree


def findSolution(istate, fstate, tree):
    """
    back track through dict and find the moves taken to get from istate and final state
    """
    solution = []
    cstate = fstate
    if fstate in tree:
        while (cstate != istate):
            #compare current state and previous
            #find the difference, record in tuple and add to list of solution moves
            pstate = tree[cstate]
            for p, c in zip(pstate, cstate):
                if p != c:
                    solution.insert(0, (p+1, c+1)) #add one to adjust for 0 offset
                    break
            cstate = pstate
        solution.insert(0, len(solution))

    return solution

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Java code which prepares the graph with neighboring configurations and solves it. I tried to use Object-Oriented way, but I still feel there might be better hack way to solve this faster. Hope it helps.

```
import FBSample.Node.Move;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.TreeMap;

/**
 *
 * @author Sada Kurapati <sadakurapati@gmail.com>
 */
public class FBSample {

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    int k = sc.nextInt();
    //pegs initial config
    Node source = readPegsConfiguration(k, n, sc);
    //read target configuration
    Node target = readPegsConfiguration(k, n, sc);
    //To keep track what config we visited and avoid cycles
    Set<Node> visited = new HashSet<Node>();
    try {
      minMovesToTarget(source, target, visited);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      System.out.println("Exception = " + ex);
    }
  }

  private static void minMovesToTarget(Node source, Node target, Set<Node> visited) throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    //Perform BFS
    //add soource node to Queue
    Queue<Node> q = new LinkedList<Node>();
    q.add(source);
    Node current = source;
    while (!q.isEmpty()) {
      current = q.poll();
      if (current.equals(target)) { //found the target configuration
        break;
      }
      List<Node> neighbors = current.neighbors();
      if (neighbors.size() > 0) {
        for (Node n : neighbors) {
          if (!visited.contains(n)) {//if not visited, put it in queue
            q.offer(n);
            visited.add(n);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    //Printing path and moves if target config found
    if (current.equals(target)) {
      printOutput(current);
    }
  }

  private static Node readPegsConfiguration(int k, int n, Scanner sc) {
    Stack<Integer>[] initialState = new Stack[k];
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
      initialState[i] = new Stack<Integer>();
    }
    //reading and reversing the line as we need to put the elements in decresing size
    //disc is key and peg is value.
    TreeMap<Integer, Integer> map = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>(Collections.reverseOrder());
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      map.put(i, sc.nextInt());
    }
    //prepare pegs
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
      initialState[entry.getValue() - 1].push(entry.getKey());
    }
    return new Node(initialState);
  }

  static void printOutput(Node target) {
    Stack<Move> stack = new Stack<>(); //using stack as we need to print the trail from Source - target config
    while (target.parent != null) {
      stack.add(target.move);
      target = target.parent;
    }
    System.out.println(stack.size());
    while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
      System.out.println(stack.pop());
    }
  }

  static class Node implements Cloneable {
    //pegs
    Stack<Integer>[] state = null;
    Node parent = null;  //for backtracking trail
    Move move = null; // The move we made to go to next neighbor config

    public Node(Stack<Integer>[] st) {
      state = st;
    }

    @Override
    protected Node clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
      Stack<Integer>[] cloneStacks = new Stack[state.length];
      for (int i = 0; i < state.length; i++) {
        cloneStacks[i] = (Stack) state[i].clone();
      }
      Node clone = new Node(cloneStacks);
      return clone;
    }

    //returns the neghboring configurations.
    //What all configurations we can get based on current config.
    public List<Node> neighbors() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
      List<Node> neighbors = new ArrayList<>();
      int k = state.length;
      for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
          if (i != j && !state[i].isEmpty()) {
            Node child = this.clone();
            //make a move
            if (canWeMove(child.state[i], child.state[j])) {
              child.state[j].push(child.state[i].pop());
              //this is required to backtrack the trail once we find the target config
              child.parent = this;
              //the move we made to get to this neighbor
              child.move = new Move(i, j);
              neighbors.add(child);
            }
          }
        }
      }
      return neighbors;
    }

    public boolean canWeMove(Stack<Integer> fromTower, Stack<Integer> toTower) {
      boolean answer = false;
      if (toTower.isEmpty()) {// if destination peg is empty, then we can move any disc
        return true;
      }
      int toDisc = toTower.peek();
      int fromDisc = fromTower.peek();
      if (fromDisc < toDisc) { //we can only place small disc on top
        answer = true;
      }
      return answer;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
      int hash = 7;
      return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
      if (obj == null) {
        return false;
      }
      if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
      }
      final Node other = (Node) obj;
      if (!Arrays.deepEquals(this.state, other.state)) {
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    }

    class Move {

      int pegFrom, pegTo;

      public Move(int f, int t) {
        pegFrom = f + 1;
        pegTo = t + 1;
      }

      @Override
      public String toString() {
        return pegFrom + " " + pegTo;
      }
    }
  }
}
```