# Input format explanation for TOH

Tags: facebook, algorithm

Today i came across this Tower of Hanoi problem from Facebook and here is the question and solution for this - [Facebook sample puzzle: Towers of Hanoi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601701/facebook-sample-puzzle-towers-of-hanoi)
But the problem i am facing is i am not able to understand the inputs given here . i know the basics of tower of Hanoi. i am not able to understand this part

Constraints:
1<= N<=8
3<= K<=5

Input Format:
N K
**2nd line contains N integers.
Each integer in the second line is in the range 1 to K where the i-th integer denotes the peg to which disc of radius i is present in the initial configuration.
3rd line denotes the final configuration in a format similar to the initial configuration.**

N and K are inputs where N is the number of disks and K is the number of pegs. But what is the initial configuration and final configuration here is an example.

```
Sample Input #00:
```

2 3

1 1

2 2

where 2 is the Number of disks and 3 is the number of pegs what the next line 1 1 and 2 2. can anyone please help me in understanding this problem and correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sample input denotes: Both disks are on the first peg, and you should move them to the second peg.

Another sample input:

```
6 4
4 2 4 3 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1
```

describes this placement:

```
5     1 
6 2 4 3
_ _ _ _
```

Comment: thanks @MBo i was able to understand. will move forward in understanding the solution.